# I have a dataset of 130 variables and I have to check the correlation of all variables, is there any way to check it in once

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, p-value, hypothesis-test

I have a dataset of 130 variables and I have to check the correlation of all variables, is there any way to check it in once I am new to data science and using pandas, please suggest a way.
Do I have to do hypothesis....

Comment: You say you want to check "it" once, but there is no clear referent for "it".  Correlation is a property of two series -- a pair of variables, or two data columns.  130 variables will have 130*129 / 2 total correlations.

Comment: Hi @Prune as I want to drop multiple variables and I guess for that I have to check the correlation of variables please correct if I am missing anything.

Comment: You're missing a research step: how to reduce variables (dimensions) in data preprocessing.  Use search terms such as "dimension reduction" and "eliminate variables".  I expect that a good starting point is "principal component analysis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could have easily found out answer to this question elsewhere** *but since you're new to datascience...*

```
# First read the dataset into a dataframe
data = pd.read_excel(file_name)

# Find correlation among all the columns (features / variables)
# methods can be changed
data.corr(method='pearson')
```